# Poles of complex function...

Tags: complex-analysis

The function is:

$f(z) = \frac{1 - e^z}{z^4sin(1 + z)} $

I know that 0 and the points $n\pi - 1$ for an integer n are singularities. I want to calculate the order of this singularities. In this case i have to calculate the principal part of the function and i'm not finding the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Find the corresponding Laurent series expansion. For $z=0$ for example, expand numerator around $z=0$:

$$1-\exp(z)=-z-\frac{1}{2}z^2-\frac{1}{6}z^3-\ldots$$

Expand $\sin(1+z)$ around $z=0$:

$$\sin(1+z)=\sin(1)+\cos(1)z-\frac{1}{2}\sin(1)z^2-\frac{1}{6}\cos(1)z^3+\frac{1}{24}\sin(1)z^4+\ldots$$

Now perform a long series division to find the first couple of terms of the ratio. Modulo LaTex typos, you will find:

$$\frac{1-\exp(z)}{z^4\cdot\sin(1+z)}=\frac{-1}{\sin(1)z^3}+\frac{-1/2+\cot(1)}{\sin(1)z^2}+\frac{-2/3-(1/2)\cdot(-\sin(1)+2\cos(1))\cdot\cos(1)/\sin(1)^2}{\sin(1)z}+stuff$$

Conclude that $z=0$ is a pole of order 3 and your residue there is the fraction that accompanies the term $\frac{1}{z}$, above.

Continue similarly with the other singularities.